# How to show the vertical indent guides of a code in minted?

Tags: indentation, minted, code

I'm using minted for a competitive programming reference, I'm using a tool that given a template lets you create a .tex file with all of your codes highlighted with minted. 
So I know that a lot of text editors like sublime text uses this vertical indent guide lines:

[image]

This lines are used to be like dotted lines that only shows during the indentation of a function, of something inside a codeblock, it is really useful in competitive programming to copy code from a indented code like this because it helps you to do not copy wrongly the code.

I hope there's a way to do this in minted and not in algorithmx.